# Cannot get a clear image requested from Photo Album using PhotoKit

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, photokit

I am using PhotoKit to fetch the photos in one of the system albums like this:

```
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:nil];
[fetchResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAssetCollection *collection, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"ALBUM NAME: %@", collection.localizedTitle);
    if ([collection.localizedTitle isEqualToString:@"Camera Roll"]) {
        PHFetchResult *photos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:nil];
        NSLog(@"PHOTOS: %ld", photos.count);
        _photos = nil;
        _photos = @[].mutableCopy;
        for (PHAsset *asset in photos) {
            [self loadImageFromPHAsset:asset];
        }
    }
}];
```

Then in my custom helper method: `(void)loadImageFromPHAsset:(PHAsset *)asset`, I have this:

```
-(void)loadImageFromPHAsset:(PHAsset *)asset
{
    PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
    CGSize targetSize = _layout.itemSize;
    [manager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:targetSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
        [_photos addObject:result];
    }];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

So I have an array of images and I present them in my `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
UIImage *image = [_photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

But what I got is like this, it is very blur, how can I make it clear?
[image]

Comment: I tried lots of combinations of the options with `PHImageRequestOptions` but still couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the targetSize should be multiplied by scale to account for the screen's scale like this,

```
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(_layout.itemSize.width*scale, _layout.itemSize.height*scale);
```

Secondly, try these options to get the exact size image,

```
//Async call returned on main thread, can return multiple times
        
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
```

Lastly, if you have performance concerns, use PHCachingManager, I have answered the question regarding performance improvements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533934/how-to-use-phcachingimagemanager/31218785#31218785)

Hope this helps you.

**Edit:**

I did not realise that the images were stored in an array. Try setting the synchronous flag in image options.

```
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.synchronous = YES;
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
```

Comment: Thanks @jarora, after implementing your code, it gets clearer but not as clear as iOS system photo album. Is it because I haven't adopt the caching mechanism?

Comment: @Boris Updated the answer. This will resolve the issue. Also mark the answer as correct if your issue gets resolved :)