# Ocassional crash on the app start

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession, ios-multithreading

I'm getting very strange crash at the start of the app. My app spawns a lot of threads (over 500, most of them are related to PLPreheatItem, I can not paste full crash log here, cause stackoverflow has limit to 30K symbols).

The problem is that I can not reproduce it on my device. Also it happens on clean install for my customer almost every run.

I am using NSURLSession with background session and NSOperationQueue with 4 concurrent operations. These are the most weak parts as I think.

Could someone suggest where do I need to dig. Cause I'm really have no idea what to do.

Thank you.

```
Incident Identifier: 3808D96D-CAA3-4DC3-9278-B1DF7CEFEF9D
CrashReporter Key:   0f11c86163cc36bdb756e72a5b65b3db93ad673d
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             ******** [1991]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/87DD6538-DE78-4B6A-9834-58FF8C2AE22F/********.app/********
Identifier:          ********
Version:             75 (1.1.8)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-10-24 15:21:42.42 +0200
Launch Time:         2016-10-24 15:21:37.37 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000018171e7c4
Triggered by Thread:  40

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181608fd8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181608e54 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a40c60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a3e964 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181968c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   GraphicsServices                0x0000000183250088 GSEventRunModal + 180
6   UIKit                           0x0000000186c56088 UIApplicationMain + 204
7   MyApp                           0x00000001000e1430 main (main.m:14)
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001815068b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: PLPreheatItem
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018162441c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018154122c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001815aa0b8 sleep + 44
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181733ca8 _waiting4memory + 16
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f6d4 _xpc_mach_port_allocate + 92
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f62c _xpc_connection_setup_reply_port + 40
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f5ac xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply + 108
7   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6f2e18 -[PLGatekeeperClient cancelCPLDownloadImageDataWithVirtualTaskIdentifiers:completionHandler:] + 332
8   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018af023d0 __59-[PLPreheatItem cancelPreheatRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 252
9   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6ec508 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e3390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181608fd8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181608e54 mach_msg + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e91dc _dispatch_mach_msg_send + 1716
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e94d8 _dispatch_mach_send_drain + 236
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e8968 _dispatch_mach_notify_merge + 308
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814da204 _dispatch_mach_notify_send_possible + 28
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d5fec _Xmach_notify_send_possible + 52
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d5adc libdispatch_internal_protocol_server + 104
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814ecfdc _dispatch_mach_notify_source_invoke + 28
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814edd48 _dispatch_kevent_mach_msg_recv + 280
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e8730 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 64
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d7648 _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: PLPreheatItem
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018162441c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018154122c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001815aa0b8 sleep + 44
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181733ca8 _waiting4memory + 16
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f6d4 _xpc_mach_port_allocate + 92
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f62c _xpc_connection_setup_reply_port + 40
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f5ac xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply + 108
7   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6f2e18 -[PLGatekeeperClient cancelCPLDownloadImageDataWithVirtualTaskIdentifiers:completionHandler:] + 332
8   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018af023d0 __59-[PLPreheatItem cancelPreheatRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 252
9   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6ec508 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e3390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: PLPreheatItem
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018162441c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018154122c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001815aa0b8 sleep + 44
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181733ca8 _waiting4memory + 16
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f6d4 _xpc_mach_port_allocate + 92
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f62c _xpc_connection_setup_reply_port + 40
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f5ac xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply + 108
7   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6f2e18 -[PLGatekeeperClient cancelCPLDownloadImageDataWithVirtualTaskIdentifiers:completionHandler:] + 332
8   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018af023d0 __59-[PLPreheatItem cancelPreheatRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 252
9   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6ec508 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e3390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  WebThread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181608fd8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181608e54 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a40c60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a3e964 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181968c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   WebCore                         0x000000018595a108 RunWebThread(void*) + 456
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816efb28 _pthread_body + 156
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816efa8c _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed028 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181608fd8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181608e54 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a40c60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a3e964 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181968c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001820e9bcc +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6   Foundation                      0x000000018245fe4c __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816efb28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816efa8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed028 thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624344 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a471c8 __CFSocketManager + 648
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816efb28 _pthread_body + 156
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816efa8c _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed028 thread_start + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 12 name:  Dispatch queue: PLPreheatItem
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018162441c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018154122c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001815aa0b8 sleep + 44
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181733ca8 _waiting4memory + 16
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f6d4 _xpc_mach_port_allocate + 92
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f62c _xpc_connection_setup_reply_port + 40
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f5ac xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply + 108
7   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6f2e18 -[PLGatekeeperClient cancelCPLDownloadImageDataWithVirtualTaskIdentifiers:completionHandler:] + 332
8   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018af023d0 __59-[PLPreheatItem cancelPreheatRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 252
9   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6ec508 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e3390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 13 name:  Dispatch queue: PLPreheatItem
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018162441c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018154122c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001815aa0b8 sleep + 44
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181733ca8 _waiting4memory + 16
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f6d4 _xpc_mach_port_allocate + 92
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f62c _xpc_connection_setup_reply_port + 40
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f5ac xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply + 108
7   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6f2e18 -[PLGatekeeperClient cancelCPLDownloadImageDataWithVirtualTaskIdentifiers:completionHandler:] + 332
8   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018af023d0 __59-[PLPreheatItem cancelPreheatRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 252
9   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6ec508 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e3390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 15 name:  Dispatch queue: PLPreheatItem
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018162441c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018154122c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001815aa0b8 sleep + 44
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181733ca8 _waiting4memory + 16
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f6d4 _xpc_mach_port_allocate + 92
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f62c _xpc_connection_setup_reply_port + 40
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f5ac xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply + 108
7   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6f2e18 -[PLGatekeeperClient cancelCPLDownloadImageDataWithVirtualTaskIdentifiers:completionHandler:] + 332
8   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018af023d0 __59-[PLPreheatItem cancelPreheatRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 252
9   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6ec508 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e3390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 21 name:  Dispatch queue: PLPreheatItem
Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018162441c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018154122c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001815aa0b8 sleep + 44
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181733ca8 _waiting4memory + 16
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f6d4 _xpc_mach_port_allocate + 92
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f62c _xpc_connection_setup_reply_port + 40
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f5ac xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply + 108
7   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6f2e18 -[PLGatekeeperClient cancelCPLDownloadImageDataWithVirtualTaskIdentifiers:completionHandler:] + 332
8   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018af023d0 __59-[PLPreheatItem cancelPreheatRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 252
9   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6ec508 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e3390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 23 name:  Dispatch queue: PLPreheatItem
Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181623f6c __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816f239c _pthread_mutex_lock_wait + 96
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816f257c _pthread_mutex_lock_slow + 296
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018153b77c vfprintf_l + 36
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018153b748 fprintf + 76
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001815411ec nanosleep + 148
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001815aa0b8 sleep + 44
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181733ca8 _waiting4memory + 16
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f6d4 _xpc_mach_port_allocate + 92
9   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f62c _xpc_connection_setup_reply_port + 40
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f5ac xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply + 108
11  AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6f2e18 -[PLGatekeeperClient cancelCPLDownloadImageDataWithVirtualTaskIdentifiers:completionHandler:] + 332
12  PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018af023d0 __59-[PLPreheatItem cancelPreheatRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 252
13  AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6ec508 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e3390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 24:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4
Thread 36 name:  Dispatch queue: PLPreheatItem
Thread 36:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018162441c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018154122c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001815aa0b8 sleep + 44
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181733ca8 _waiting4memory + 16
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f6d4 _xpc_mach_port_allocate + 92
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f62c _xpc_connection_setup_reply_port + 40
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f5ac xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply + 108
7   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6f2e18 -[PLGatekeeperClient cancelCPLDownloadImageDataWithVirtualTaskIdentifiers:completionHandler:] + 332
8   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018af023d0 __59-[PLPreheatItem cancelPreheatRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 252
9   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6ec508 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e3390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 37 name:  Dispatch queue: PLPreheatItem
Thread 37:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018162441c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018154122c nanosleep + 212
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001815aa0b8 sleep + 44
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181733ca8 _waiting4memory + 16
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f6d4 _xpc_mach_port_allocate + 92
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f62c _xpc_connection_setup_reply_port + 40
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171f5ac xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply + 108
7   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6f2e18 -[PLGatekeeperClient cancelCPLDownloadImageDataWithVirtualTaskIdentifiers:completionHandler:] + 332
8   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018af023d0 __59-[PLPreheatItem cancelPreheatRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 252
9   AssetsLibraryServices           0x000000018a6ec508 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d54bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e14c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d8f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e3390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 38:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 39:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181624b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 40 name:  Kernel bug: The kernel cannot allocate memory needed for the ps  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 40 Crashed:
0   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171e7c4 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 776
1   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018171e7c4 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 776
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d5578 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d9864 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 656
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e1694 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d8978 _dispatch_mach_invoke + 600
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814d547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e3914 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001814e30b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816ed020 start_wqthread + 4

Activity ID:             0x0000000000156343
Activity Name:           starting resolver activity
Activity Image Path:     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
Activity Image UUID:     A8E4200A-ECC7-3E56-A845-8A0E9CB4A6F0
Activity Offset:         0x0003333c
Activity Running Time:   5.357751 sec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems the issue is resolved.

At the start of the app I was creating `PHCachingImageManager` and calling `startCachingImagesForAssets:targetSize:contentMode:options:`. I was doing this for all iCloud assets that user have, so If you have a lot of assets to cache be careful just to start caching all of them immediately.

As the result `PHCachingImageManager`spawned dozens of threads in serial queue for each asset separately. (more than 500 for my customer). So application finally run out of memory.

Here is workaround people do for this: [How to use PHCachingImageManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533934/how-to-use-phcachingimagemanager)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is truncated.  It is apparently "The kernel cannot allocate memory needed for the pseudo-receive."

You're probably running up against the maximum number of threads that the device can handle concurrently.  500 threads translates to about half a gigabyte of RAM just for your app's thread stacks, before you even construct a heap or allocate backing storage for the screen.  On a device with 512 MB of RAM (iPhone 4S and lower, iPod Touch 5th generation and lower, iPad 2 and earlier, iPad Mini 1st generation and earlier), there's no prayer that it will ever work.  And even on newer devices, that's horribly abusive.

It looks like this is being triggered by something you're doing with Apple's Photos framework.  If you're doing something that involves looking at metadata on a large number of pictures or something, you should add delays or something to limit the rate at which you do so.  Beyond that, there may well be nothing you can do other than filing a bug report at bugreport.apple.com and hoping for the best.