# iOS photo app with scrolling and zoom by pinch

Tags: ios, photo

Any ideas how to deal with 10-50-100-250k of photos and smooth scrolling and zooming by pinch? Like in native Photo app

Checked https://github.com/dreampowder/photosSample with ~11k on 6s. Works not very fast..
(from [How can IOS Photos app can show hundreds of photos in one screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297836/how-can-ios-photos-app-can-show-hundreds-of-photos-in-one-screen/))

Wrote custom zooming and scrolling by pinch but how to be with grid of ~2k photos (~2k per screen)...? Load such amount of photos while scrolling looks like bad idea. Preload all of them and show preloaded image of grid..? Sounds not very good too. And how to be with floating positions when zooming by pinch if doing this way..? Now I'm loading photos with PHImageManager.default().requestImage but it seems there should be other way or some specific options.. I'm not sure that PHImageManager.default().requestImage use presaved thumbnails of photos. How to be sure that it's not cropping photos on the fly?

ps: gone trying to make something with PHCachingImageManager

ps2: see no difference between PHCachingImageManager and PHImageManager.default =(

Now I generate UIImage from ~2000k photos (to show grid of 33 23px images like in native photo app). Loading them takes time.. moved loading of them to background thread. Updating display UIImage after loading each image from disk and it looks like dial up html page... but it works.. and background loading not freezes an app, trying to dial with it while scrolling and pinching (zooming) and looking for better solutions

Any ideas? Found not only not very clear working of pinch in native apple app but even bugs when some photos not presented at some grid scales (they can appear and disappear depending on zoom. could check it for example with new photos. try to add about 10k photos). It looks like apple cheating creating pre-saved grid of something more/else.

May be someone found Photos source codes?